# Tabcontrol  with scrollable tabitems using silverlight 

Tags: c#, silverlight, tabcontrol

Hi friends,                                                                                      Am newbie for windows Development .i have created Grid With tabcontrol using silvelight OOB(out of browser app) .Able to add tabitem at run time by following code

```
TabItem tabItem = new TabItem();
tabItem.Header = "tab";
tabControl.Items.Add(tabItem);
```

While adding more no of tabitems, tabitems are  added to new line automatically ,instead of scroll enable like google chrome browser.Any property is there to add Scroll??? 
            i have gone through msdn documents but couldn't find anything.Some of the stackoverflow answers say third parties control but am not interested to use those.i want to do my own .Possible give some guidance to get my solution.

Comment: how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have scrollable tabs in stead of having them appear on multiple lines, you will need to either create you own tabcontrol from scratch, or create a tab control style in which you override the control template.

If you are completely new to silverlight (and xaml), this might be too difficult for you to do. I do not believe there is a simple way to do this, as this functionality is just not part of the standard tab control.